# Give Mysql Columns a name made of just a number

Tags: php, mysql

Im writing a PHP script which allows a user to create a Mysql table by filling in the values they want in a HTML form and then processing them into Mysql query.

This works fine however or one such table the user needs to be able to set numbers as the name of some of the table columns, this does not work and results in the below mysql error:

```
No TABLE created. Check You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '45 double, 55 double, 45 double )' at line 5
```

The MySql looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE rates_ 
( 
   Weight int(11), 
   Length double, 
   Strength double, 
   Min double, 
   45 double, 
   55 double, 
   45 double 
)
```

However when I create the table using phpMyAdmin the table is created fine, is there a special way to create tables with numbers as their column name?

Comment: Do not use numbers for(or at the start of) table/column identifiers. And in any case, duplicate column names are obviously not allowed.

Comment: You've got a duplicate column name in there!

Comment: I wonder how many days of happiness you'll have because you let some people who have no clue about anything create actual tables using an HTML form :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place backticks `

around the column names

```
CREATE TABLE rates_ (
    `Weight` int(11),
    `Length` double,
    `Strength` double,
    `Min` double,
    `45` double,
    `55` double
);
```

Also notice that `45` is used twice.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the duplicate column name

Comment: You probably also need to escape the `Min` column as that is a reserved word